# Show that $(-1)^{n}\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} \right)=\tfrac{(-1)^{n}}{2\sqrt{n}}+\mathcal{O}\left(\tfrac{1}{n^{3/2}} \right)$

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

> I would like to show that :
>   $$\fbox{$(-1)^{n}\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} \right)=\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{2\sqrt{n}}+\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{1}{n^{3/2}} \right)$}$$
>   by starting from the left side and get the right side

My Proof:

\begin{align*}
(-1)^{n}\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} \right)&=(-1)^{n}\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n} }\right)\\
&=(-1)^{n}\left(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n} \right)^{-1}\\
&=(-1)^{n}\left(\sqrt{n}\left(1+\sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{n}}\right) \right)^{-1}\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{\sqrt{n}}\left(1+\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{\dfrac{1}{2}} \right)^{-1}\\
&=\mbox{Note that :}\left(1+x\right)^{\alpha}=1+\mathcal{O}\left( x\right) \\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{\sqrt{n}}\left(1+\left(1+\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{1}{n} \right)\right) \right)^{-1}\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{\sqrt{n}}\left(2+\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right) \right)^{-1}\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{2\sqrt{n}}\left(1+\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right) \right)^{-1}\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{2\sqrt{n}}\left(1+\mathcal{O}\left(\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\right) \right)\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{2\sqrt{n}}\left(1+\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right) \right)\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{2\sqrt{n}}+\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{1}{n^{3/2}} \right)\\
\end{align*}
$$\fbox{$(-1)^{n}\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} \right)=\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{2\sqrt{n}}+\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{1}{n^{3/2}} \right)$}$$

- Am i right ?

Comment: Please use `\tfrac` in titles, in this case we can simply write $\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{1}{n^{\dfrac{3}{2}}} \right)$ as $\mathcal{O}\left(n^{-3/2}\right)$.

Comment: okay, it's  Done !

Comment: $n^a - (n+1)^a = a\int_{n}^{n+1} x^{a-1} dx = a n^{a-1} + a\int_{n}^{n+1} (x^{a-1}- n^{a-1}) dx$ $ = a n^{a-1} + a(a-1)\int_{n}^{n+1} \int_n^x y^{a-2}dy dx =  a n^{a-1} + \frac{a(a-1)}2 \mathcal{O}(n^{a-2})$. but your method with the Taylor expansion of $f(x) = (1+x)^a$ at $x = 0$ works too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct to me. In short,
$$
\begin{align}
(-1)^{n}\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} \right)&=(-1)^{n}\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}
\\\\&=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\frac1{1+\sqrt{1+1/n}}
\\\\&=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\frac1{1+1+O(1/n)}
\\\\&=\frac{(-1)^n}{2\sqrt{n}}\left(1-O(1/n) \right)
\\\\&=\frac{(-1)^n}{2\sqrt{n}}+O\left(\frac1{n^{3/2}} \right).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you since i work on book of "j'intégre monier mp " which gives only the final resultat withtout details

Comment: You are welcome. I don't know the book, but Monier is a solid reference for calculus.

Comment: @Educ Tell me please if you are you Ok with my answer above. Thanks.

Comment: yes of course it's fine Thank you now i'm stuck in other problem i will post it

Answer (score 1):

You van do it also by purely algebraic means:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}+\frac{\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n+1}}{2\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}\\
&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})^2}.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Simply using series expansion will do:

\begin{align*}
  \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} &= \sqrt{n} \left( \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}-1 \right) \\
  &=\sqrt{n} \left( 1+\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{8n^2}+\ldots-1 \right) \\
  &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{8n^{3/2}}+\ldots
\end{align*}